# Position not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need point 0:0 in left top on table.

Now position the mouse is measured from the top page

```
   <h2>
        TestPosition</h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" id="target" cellspacing="0" width="602" height="500" style="float: left;
        margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; background: url(/content/games/kamikaze2/back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;">
    </table>
    <div id="log">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#target").mousemove(function (event) {
            var thisPosX = $(this).position().left;
            var thisPosY = $(this).position().top;

            var relX = (event.clientX - thisPosX);
            var relY = (event.clientY - thisPosY);

            var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
            msg += relX + ", " + relY;
            $("#log").html("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

```
function localMouse(event, element)
{
    var offset = $(element).offset();
    return [event.pageX - offset.left, event.pageY - offset.top];
}
```